# Why Visual Studio doesnt recognize the installed package?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, python-import, python-packaging

I have installed pyttsx3 package at the same environment that my .py file in Visual Studio Community 2019, but it is not recognized by using "import".

I´ve tried other two different packages, but the problem remains. (environment: Python 3.6 (64-bit), Visual Studio Community 2019 )

`import pyttsx3`

`engine = pyttsx3.init()`
`engine.say("Hi there!")`
`engine.runAndWait()`

"unresolved import pyttsx3" message showed.

Answer (score 0):

The error message remains, but now the code is running. It make no sense!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
python -m venv <myenvname>
```

Will create a virtual environment
that then you could just install with pip

```
pip install <packagename>
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. I know how to access command line (terminal) on Visual Studio Code, but not in Community (I even googled it, and I cant find how). Anyway, I had already used pip install by Visual Studio Community environment packages window. You had the same problem?